# How to filter records with approval history

Tags: approval-process, approval-history

I'm trying to view records of a particular sObject with non-empty approval history. Is there a way to get it either from the UI or using SOQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a report based on **Approval Process Instance** report type and filter the report using **Object type** filter.